# Log4J2 Thousands Delimiter

Tags: java, log4j2

Anybody an idea how I include the delimiter for the thousand power in big numbers using the `{}` annotation?

```
log.info("Reading {} entries (multiplied with one million)", entries * 1_000_000);
```

Output (currently):

```
Reading 80000000 entries (multiplied with one million)
```

Output (desired):

```
Reading 80,000,000 entries (multiplied with one million)
```

Is there a way to realize this directly in Log4J2 without using an additional formatter like e.g. `DecimalFormat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call one of the logger methods, Log4j2 creates a [`Message`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message.html), which usually has a fixed string representation.

Most methods create [`ParameterizedMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html)s (cf. [available messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/messages.html)), that use [`StringBuilder#append`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to format your parameters. This does not provide any alternative representation for integers.

If you want a different format you can:

1. Use [`Logger#printf`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#printf-org.apache.logging.log4j.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which interprets your format string using [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) and creates a [`StringFormattedMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/StringFormattedMessage.html):

   ```java
   log.printf(Level.INFO, "Reading %,d entries (multiplied with one million)",
           entries * 1_000_000);
   ```

   As you can deduce from the method signature, it always creates a temporary object array and is not garbage-free.
2. When you create your logger, you can specify a different [`MessageFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/MessageFactory.html). If you use [StringFormatterMessageFactory](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/StringFormatterMessageFactory.html), **all** your messages will be formatted with `java.util.Formatter`:

   ```java
   final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class,
           StringFormatterMessageFactory.INSTANCE);
   log.info("Reading %,d entries (multiplied with one million)", entries * 1_000_000);
   ```

   This solution does **not** create temporary object arrays.
3. You can also use [`FormattedMessageFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/FormattedMessageFactory.html), which dynamically determines if your format string conforms to `java.util.Formatter`, `java.text.MessageFormat` or uses simple `{}` placeholders. This flexibility, of course, comes at a slight performance cost.